# Renormalization of the $O(N)$ vector model - integral

Tags: renormalization, path-integral, regularization

I am following the steps made in the review https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06784.

there, at page 14 the author proceeds to find a specific logarithmic term for $\frac{\partial U_{eff}}{\partial \sigma}$ which is

$$
\frac{N}{32 \pi^2} \sigma \ln(\frac{\sigma} {M^2})
$$

It is unclear to me how does he reach this result as when I try to find it by myself I reach the following step

$$ \frac{N}{2}  \sigma \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2 (k^2 + M^2)} -  N \int \frac{d^4 k }{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{N}{2} \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2 + \sigma^2} $$ 
$$= \frac{N}{32 \pi^2} \sigma \ln(\frac{\sigma} {M^2}) $$

however when using spherical coordinates, none of these terms on the LHS can give a logarithm even if I use a cut off scale for $k^2$

what am I missing?

Comment: Please double check your formula. Shouldn't $\frac{N}{2}  \sigma \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2 (k^2 + M^2)} -  N \int \frac{d^4 k }{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{N}{2} \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2 + \sigma^2}
$ be $\frac{N}{2}  \sigma \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2 (k^2 + M^2)} -  \frac{N}{2} \int \frac{d^4 k }{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{N}{2} \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2 + \sigma}
$ instead?